# Access MSN mail account in application

Tags: ios, email, msn

I would like to access MSN account access in application.

How to do this?

Please suggest; can I get the web services from MSN?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is a bit vague, however I will still try to answer. At the moment the only API I know that provides access to Windows Live services using Objective C is that of the [Live SDK for iOS](https://github.com/liveservices/LiveSDK-for-iOS)

> The Live SDK for iOS library is intended to help developers to easily integrate SkyDrive and Hotmail contacts and calendars into their iOS apps.
>
> The repository here includes:
>
> Live SDK Library source (src/LiveSDK/Library)
> Live SDK framework (bin/LiveSDK.framework.zip)
> Samples (src/samples)

You can acquire documentation and additional help from [Live Connect Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh875197.aspx).